# Set multiple alarms using request code

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I wanna set multiple alarm using request code.
I give different values of the request codes to each alarm, but the alarmManager still executes only the last set alarm.
Here's my existing code:

```
public void Alarm(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadCast.class);
        alarmID = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000000000); //for request code

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            MainActivity.this, alarmID, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                     calendar.get(Calendar.DATE),hours,mins,0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                               calendar.getTimeInMillis(),am.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
    }
```

Comment: could you check your alarm id?

Comment: yes. i check them by toast. and they have different values.

Answer (score 0):

try setRepeating instead of setInexactRepeating  you will get repeating alarm.

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (5 * 1000),5 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Android 5.1 (API version 22) there is a minimum period of 1 minute for repeating alarms. If you need to do work within one minute, just set the alarm directly, then set the next one from that alarm's handler, etc. If you need to do work within 5 seconds (for example), post it to a Handler instead of using the AlarmManager.

Good documetion here :

https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/

Comment: Just for clarity, the handler requires the app to be active, the alarm-manager does not. So the design has to this point into consideration.